# navigating from a tab screen to a stack screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native

For an IOS application, I have a stack that gets called in my tab navigator. I am trying to navigate from a bottom tab screen to a screen in the stack but I am getting the following error.

> undefined is not an object (evaluating
> '_this.props.navigation.navigate')

I would like to render the bottom tab across all screens. I am noticing this causes some interesting issues with goBack() as well in other places.

**How can I navigate from the bottom tab screen to a stack screen?**

**Is the current implementation a bad practice?**

I have provided this [demo](https://snack.expo.dev/@priedejm/bottom-tab-to-stack-screen) as well as the following code below. I think it is related to prop passing.

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function MyTabs() {
  return (

     <Stack.Navigator
     initialRouteName="Home">        
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component= {Home} options={{headerShown: false}}/>
      <Stack.Screen name="Screen1" component= {Screen1} options={{headerShown: false}}/> 
    </Stack.Navigator>
);

);
}

export default function App() {

  return (
  <NavigationContainer>
    <Tab.Navigator
    initialRouteName="Home"
    screenOptions={{
      tabBarActiveTintColor: '#F60081',
      tabBarInactiveTintColor: '#4d4d4d',
      tabBarStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#d1cfcf',
        borderTopColor: 'transparent',
      },
    }} 
  >
    <Tab.Screen
      name="Home"
      component={MyTabs}
      options={{
        tabBarLabel: 'Home',
        headerShown: false,
        tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
          <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={size} />
        ),
      }}
    />
    
  </Tab.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
);
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
```

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  ImageBackground,
} from 'react-native';
const Images = [
  { id: '1', uri: require('./assets/snack-icon.png'), text: 'Test' },
  { id: '2', uri: require('./assets/snack-icon.png') /*text: "Test"*/ },
  { id: '3', uri: require('./assets/snack-icon.png') /*text: "Test"*/ },
  { id: '4', uri: require('./assets/snack-icon.png') /*text: "Test"*/ },
];

export default class Home extends React.Component {

thisNavigate = () => {
  this.props.navigation();
};

  renderList = (props) => {
    return Images.map((item, i) => {
      return (
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => this.props.thisNavigate.navigate('Screen2')}>
            <ImageBackground
              source={item.uri}
              style={{
                width: '100%',
                height: 100,
                shadowColor: '#000',
                shadowOffset: { width: 1, height: 4 },
                shadowOpacity: 1,
              }}
              imageStyle={{ borderRadius: 10 }}></ImageBackground>
          </TouchableOpacity>
      );
    });
  };

  render() {
    return <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>{this.renderList()}</View>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Issue is not on that screen, Issue will be on you tab screen. where you click on that function. if you are using word "{navigation}" under the main component remove it and use "const navigation = useNavigation() ;". it will solve your issue. you can also share of your tab screen code.

Comment: @TalhaAkbar I updated the post to include the code you mentioned. When I added the const navigation it gave me useNavigation is undefined. Any idea how I could go about it after looking at the updated code? Thank you for any insight at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example your Home component is:

```
export default class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <Screen1/> // here navigation is not passed because it is rendered not by navigator but manually
  }
}
```

Just remove it, remove its `Stack.Screen` from `MyTabs` and set initialRouteName to Screen1, and it will work.

**EDIT:**

If you want to keep Home as it is, pass navigation like that:

```
export default class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <Screen1 navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
  }
}
```

Or use [useNavigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation/) hook instead of props in `Screen1` to get navigation.

**EDIT2:**

Working [demo](https://snack.expo.dev/Py3LaIut8).

Comment: In my overall project, I use conditional rendering on the home screen, I need to return that screen there.

Comment: This seems right for sure. I think I am missing a small piece. Do you mind looking at my updated code and snack to see what I might be doing wrong? I think the issue is how I am calling it in Screen1. Thank you @Alexander Danilov

Comment: @JustinPriede added working demo.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to wrap your component withNavigation HOC
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/with-navigation/

That's because your component not directly from the component Navigator, so they don't have `this.props.navigation`, to make your component have navigation props in Class Component, you need to wrap your component using withNavigation HOC

example:

```
// Screen1.js
class Home extends React.Component {
  renderList = (props) => {
    return Images.map((item, i) => {
      return (
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Screen2')}>
            <ImageBackground
              source={item.uri}
              style={{
                width: '100%',
                height: 100,
                shadowColor: '#000',
                shadowOffset: { width: 1, height: 4 },
                shadowOpacity: 1,
              }}
              imageStyle={{ borderRadius: 10 }}></ImageBackground>
          </TouchableOpacity>
      );
    });
  };

  render() {
    return <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>{this.renderList()}</View>;
  }
}

export default withNavigation(Home);
```

sorry, but I think withNavigation is removed from v5 / v6

but you can make one like this

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

// withNavigation.js
export default function withNavigation(WrappedComponent) {
   return (props) => {
      const navigation = useNavigation();
      return <Component navigation={navigation} {...props} />
   }
}
```

Comment: So I spent some time trying this out and I unfortunately could not get it to work. I could be making a mistake though. Did you confirm this indeed works with the demo I provided? Thank you for the time you put into this though, I appreciate it more than you know.